# PostgreSQL schema design

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, schema-design, database-tools

What is your preferred way of designing PostgreSQL schemata? Would you recommend the use of specific graphical design tools or just design the schema on paper and create everything by hand?

Comment: You should try GenMyModel (https://www.genmymodel.com) it supports online database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

- [OpenModelSphere](http://www.modelsphere.org/)
- [SQL Power Architect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/)

for creating ER diagrams.

For managing the DDL scripts, I have good experience with Liquibase and Power Architect can also create the Liquibase XML directly from the ER diagram.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Community Edition](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) of [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) for creating pretty pictures of my schema - but I'd rather create the DDL that actually runs on my database by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use paper or sketch the schema directly in psql prompt.

Many UML tools have DDL-generation (see argouml), but in my experience it's faster to write the schema directly. Then you can test it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Use only in windows unfortunately, EMS SQL Manager is very good

http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager

Answer (score 1):

[pgModeler](http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/) licensed under GPL, multiplatform.

Binary installer costs 4$, I think it's worth it.

Comment: This looks very promising; it's quite new isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps this is an old thread, but I checked the Mac installer and it's closer to $120 in 2019